# Stereo EEVEE shadows not the same between Left & Right frames

Tags: rendering, shadows, stereoscopy

I have a scene setup with EEVEE which renders a stereo pair of Left and Right images.  The scene uses area lights with soft shadows.  After the render, the shadows in the Left and Right images do not match.

The Left image render looks correct, but the Right image does not have the soft shadows that the Left image has. The Right image seems to not be rendering with soft shadows somehow. The shadows are rendering sharper.

I've also tried switching the lights to the other types (point, sun, spot) and get the same incorrect result. The shadows should match between Left and Right renders. I've tried this with Blender 2.92, and now, currently with 2.93.5.